# Detection returns huge number of keypoints

Tags: c++, opencv

using following code (snippet of the relevant parts) I try to perform a keypoint detection with OpenCV 2.4.11:

```
IplImage                   *fiducial;
cv::SiftFeatureDetector     siftDetector;
cv::SurfFeatureDetector     surfDetector(400);
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>   siftKeypoints,surfKeypoints;

...

siftDetector.detect(fiducial,siftKeypoints);
surfDetector.detect(fiducial,surfKeypoints);
```

After the calls to detect() both vectors siftKeypoints and surfKeypoints come back with an incredibly huge number of keypoints (658812288344697520). Amazingly detect() has no return value which could inform about an error and it also does not throw an exception.

So...what could be wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that `siftKeypoints.size()` has such a value ? This is highly unlikely. Could you edit question and add the line that prints that value ?

Comment: OKm, solved, it was a mismatch between DEBUG-build and RELEASE-libraries!

Comment: @Elmi please post that as the answer

Answer (score 2):

Solved, it was a mismatch between DEBUG-build and RELEASE-libraries.

Comment: Good find. I spent hours on this one